# Will the uncommitted change also will push along in Git?

Tags: git

We follow the Gitflow model.  I am trying to merge my branch to develop now.  But I have some uncommitted changes also in my branch.  I merged successfully. Now the question is when i push my changes to remote, will my uncommitted changes also Push along ?  I don't want my uncommitted files to go along as they are required for local testing purpose only.   Please do clarify.

Comment: No. If you don't do a commit before pushing it, you will not push your uncommitted files.
In the case that you want to push some new files, you can select just the files you need with git add "YOUR_FILES". Then the git commit will only contain that files

Comment: @pcampana This is not a comment, but an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Conceptually speaking, Git has 4 areas: Working, Staging, Repository and Stash.

1. Whenever you change something, that's present in Working area.
2. You need to do `git add fileName` or `git add .` [to add all changes] to move your files to staging area.
3. Only those files can be committed which are in staging area.
4. All the committed files reside in repository area. Only commits can be pushed to remote.

Hence, your uncommitted changes won't be pushed to remote in any scenario unless you commit those and then do `git push`.